# Math Formula is too long exceeds column width

Tags: formatting, pdftex, amsmath, width

I have a formula below which is expected to be in an column. After compiled, it is too long and covers two column. How can I constrain it into only one column width? Thanks

```
\begin{equation}
  f'(u,v) =
  \begin{cases}
    false, &  \text{S(u)!=S(v), u $\in$ G and v $\in$ G'} \\
    F(Edge(s_0), Edge'(s_0)) \land ...\land F(Edge(s_k), Edge'(s_k)), & \text{S(u)!=$\emptyset$, i=1,..,k}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `\bigwedge` command (like `\sum`) to agrupate Edge's: `\displaystyle\bigwedge_{i=0}^k F(Edge(s_i),Edge'(s_i))` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition by cases in two column format are always a pain. Here's a possibility, with some fixes:

1. “false” should not be in italics, as it's a (non numeric) constant;
2. “Edge” seems to be an operator, so I treated it as such
3. what's math should always be in math mode

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to provide mock text

\DeclareMathOperator{\Edge}{Edge}
\newcommand{\false}{\mathrm{false}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
f'(u,v) =
\begin{cases}
  \false,\\
  \hfill\quad \text{for $S(u)\ne S(v)$, $u \in G$, $v \in G'$} \\[2\jot]
  \bigwedge\limits_{i=0}^{k} F(\Edge(s_i), \Edge'(s_i)), \\
  \hfill\quad \text{for $S(u)\ne\emptyset$, $i=1,\dots,k$}
\end{cases}\!\! % some backing up, so the equation number fits
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

I have some doubts about the condition `i=1,...,k` that appears in the second condition, as in your original code there's no `i` (and in mine it's just a dummy index).

[image]